# Cant get kivy animation to work with pos_hint

Tags: python, kivy

I want a widget to move with the animation function, instead of using pos, I want to use pos_hint as it simplifies a lot of things. When the animation starts, it sets the pos_hint to an empty {} for some reason. I think it has something to do with binding pos_hint properly to button or maybe anim isn't sending the pos_hint values correctly.

I've tried using pos and it works fine.

```
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.animation import *
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<FloatLayout>:
    button:
        size_hint: 1,1/4
        pos_hint: {'center_y':0.5,'right':0}
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: [1,0,1,1]
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
""")

class button(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ButtonSr, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        def checkpos(inst,val):
            print(val) #prints {} as soon as self.startanim() is fired and 
                        nothing else. pos_hint stays as {}

        self.bind(pos_hint=checkpos)
        self.startanim()

    def startanim(self):
        anim = Animation(pos_hint={'center_x':0.5},d=2)
        anim.start(self)
```

I want button to move from outside of the screen to the chosen pos_hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a separate variable that defines the position hint you want to change in the kv code. Then in your animation, change that variable instead of trying to change the `pos_hint` attribute.

in kv:

```
my_y_hint: .5
pos_hint: {"center_y": self.my_y_hint, "right": 0}
```

Then in your animation:

```
anim = Animation(my_y_hint=1)
```

I also made a [quick video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cN7ANPNkIaw) on how to do this recently.